# Installing php on Ubuntu 8.10; package not found?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, apt-get, repository

I'm new to linux. For some work I need to install php but not necessarily apache as I'm using my own webserver.
I'm using Ubuntu 8.10. But when I try to install php I get the following error.

```
root@ubuntu:/home/sam/WS/webserver#  apt-get install php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
.E: Couldn't find package php5
```

same type of error if I try to install apache as well. I read on web that it's a repository related problem. When I try a 'apt-get update' I get 404 errors. I have pasted this output at http://pastebin.com/g74DNzxL.

Please tell me how do I install php on ubuntu 8.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a really old version of ubuntu and is no longer supported. You're better off upgrading to a new version of ubuntu (preferably the latest LTS). You won't get updates, things could break, you have outdated packages without the latest security and functionality patches. *I SERIOUSLY RECOMMEND UPGRADING*

Now that we're done with that...

Apparently you MIGHT be able to access older repos by changing your sources.lst to have the last update of the repos from EOLed repositories.[(source)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1630769). Rename your /etc/sources.lst to sources.lst.old, and paste the below into a new /etc/sources.lst file

```
## EOL upgrade sources.list
# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-security main restricted universe multiverse
# Optional
#deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

`apt-get update && apt-get install php5`
and hope its still up. This is not a good idea, and not really tested

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is not working is that the Ubuntu main repositories have removed the packages for Ubuntu 8.10, because it's:

- Not a Long Term Support (LTS) release; and
- It's **extremely** old (the "8" in the version number is for the year **2008**, which now is about 4 years ago). In terms of the rate of evolution of the Linux desktop, using a 4 year old distribution is the equivalent of driving a car from 1935.

There is a mirror for ancient packages [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) with a working apt repository as well as ISO image downloads. You can point your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to this location instead of the default repo.

However, I would very strongly recommend that you stop trying to use such an old distribution. If you need to use something old and stable that's supported for a long time, you have two options:

- As a first option, use Ubuntu 12.04, released in April 2012. If this works for what you want to do, *great*.
- As a second option, use Ubuntu 10.04, released in April 2010. If this works for what you want to do, that's *fine*.
- As a final option, use Ubuntu 8.04, released in April 2008. This is actually *older* than Ubuntu 8.10, but it is officially supported on Ubuntu Server until April 2013.

See [this Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) which describes the Ubuntu release lifecycle, where you have several standard releases (usually 3) which each become unsupported after a very short time (a year and a half), followed by a long-term support release which is maintained for security and bugfix updates for a very long time (4 years for desktops, and 7 years for servers).